# Making items appear from obstacles in game?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game using Pygame where there are random obstacles on the screen (like boxes). The boxes can be removed by the player when they place a bomb next to it. I have some items that I would like to have randomly appear in place of the box if it is removed. I'm not sure how to go about this logically. Does anyone have any tips? No code is necessary (but helpful), I just want some steps logic-wise to get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the box removed you need to call a ~destructor function on it, which would remove the image of the box and so on correct?

Take advantage of that and create a function that chooses which item to spawn (could be random, up to you) in the position where the box used to be.

Then call this function at the end of the destructor. That's how imagine it working.